# How can i use *ngIf condition in below code?

Tags: ionic-framework

Here I want to check the condition but I am not able to check.

```
 <text-avatar id="av" item-start [text]="item.BN" [color]="item.color">                      

     <ion-icon id="check" name="checkmark-circle" float-start></ion-icon>                      

 </text-avatar>
```

Comment: So you want to show a check mark when something has done, right ?

Comment: Yes !! Correct.. you got my problem

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that, where `someBoolean` can be any boolean value retrieved through component class

**home.tst**

```
. . .

class Home {
   var someBoolean: boolean = false;
   var myArray: any[];

   constructor() {
      // compare values with array here or in any other method
      if (true) {
         someBoolean = true;
      }
   }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<text-avatar id="av" item-start [text]="item.BN" [color]="item.color" *ngIf="someBoolean">                      

     <ion-icon id="check" name="checkmark-circle" float-start></ion-icon>                      

 </text-avatar>
```

Comment: i have to Check Multiple and Compare with array

Comment: How i would compare single value to Array[1,2]